Edge label is getting overlapping in one another
const newEdge = {
    ...params,
    type: 'smoothstep',
    label: ``,
    animated: true,
    markerEnd: { type: "arrowclosed" },
    style: {
      stroke: color ? color : " #a6acaf",
    },
    labelStyle: {
      fontSize: "14px",
      fontWeight: "bold",
      borderRadius: "50%",
      display: "flex",
      alignItems: "center",
      justifyContent: "center",
      textAlign: "center",
      lineHeight: "10px",
      color: "#fff",
      fill: "#fff",
    },
    labelShowBg: true,
    labelBgStyle: {
      backgroundColor: color,
      borderRadius: "50%",
      fill: color,
      width: "25px",
      height: "26px",
    },
    labelBgPadding: [6, 6],
    labelBgBorderRadius: 15,
  };

Using above code i am creating my edge and label with styles here problem is ,once i have two nodes and i am trying interconnect both and giving diferent edge label for both node edge connections but both are getting overlapped on one another and i am not able to see which is down the overlapped one.I have tried transform but its not working once edge is created its created as svg so the label wrapper is a  element.
CODE REFERENCE :
transform: translate(-50%, -50%) translate(${labelX}px,${labelY}px), This is the basic style will be appended once label got added ,so the label will centered in the middle .
EXPECTED SOLUTION :
Randomize the edge label position for all the edge which is getting created as new edge
EXAMPLE CODESANDBOX URL
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-xyflow-forked-kththf?workspaceId=bc37d062-c51a-4f21-af04-dec30eb8d9d6

Please share your HTML structure as well. A minified verson

@Hilory Please check this sandbox link https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-xyflow-forked-kththf?workspaceId=bc37d062-c51a-4f21-af04-dec30eb8d9d6
